# Is it possible to display progress on App icon

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Is there a way to display **progress** on **Ios App icon** on the launcher/ main screen like they have default when installing or downloading an app from App store?

I have content that is being downloaded/uploaded in the background. I want to display continuous progress on app icon.
A circular progress bar is not important. I am just looking if there is any  provision for such situations.

[image]

Comment: That's a big no. But thanks for quick replying. It would have been awesome if there was such thing.

Comment: Dynamic app icons is a feature developers have been asking Apple for quite a while now. You see the clock and calendar apps do it, so it's possible but with private apis. File a [radar](https://bugreport.apple.com/) with Apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.

Apple does expose any API methods for adding a layer to the app icon on the springboard.

Also changing your apps icon to include the progress will not work, since the app icon is in your apps main bundle which is readonly.

Comment: I was just wondering if apple has exposed any of that apis. I eventually figured it out that it is not possible at the moment. Thanks for time.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if it is still possible to use these red numbers like for whatsapp when you receive a message. [image: red number]

Maybe that would be an idea. You could Show the "%" of the upload/download that way.

Comment: Yea. I thought about it for a while. I can display a badge icon anytime but I was just wondering if I can do it like the apple. Anyways thanks for your time.